# Build docker image with python application using PyQt4 library

Tags: python, docker, pyqt4, docker-build

I am trying to dockerise a small python application. The python code uses the PyQt4 library. The app has some test units which I run when I build the image. Something like the following:

```
RUN [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "source activate conda_environment && python -m unittest tests/tests_html_consistency.py" ]
```

The PyQt4 library in the python code needs a X server to do its things, but docker do not have one, therefore, unfortunately when I build the image I get the following error:

```
python -m unittest: cannot connect to X server
```

On other similar stack questions I found that a possible solution would be to simply mount the socket for the X server as a Docker volume and tell Docker to use that instead.

```
docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY TheImage
```

But how do I do this at image build time? The above command works only when the image is already build, at 'docker run' time. Moreover, if the host machine is an aws instance (hence without x server) would that work? I don't think so...

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `--build-arg` command so:

`docker build -t yourContainer --build-arg DISPLAY=$DISPLAY .`

Comment: nope, it did't work. Same error. But thanks for the suggestion, it makes sense.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?